# How can I run PHP code in an specific html section

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a section in my .html page where I want to run some PHP code, which reads data from a database and 'echoes' the table filled up with that information. I kinda did it object-oriented so I'm trying to keep that along the project.

I have this exact function or method in the Class (Class Servicio):

```
    public static function listaServicios(){
        
        $servicios = array();

        $query = "";

        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $query = "SELECT descripcion, precio FROM servicio";

        $resultado = $db->conn()->query($query);       

        foreach($resultado as $item){
            $servicio = new Servicio();
            $servicio->setDescripcion($item['descripcion']);
            $servicio->setPrecio($item['precio']);

            array_push($servicios,$servicio);
        }
        return $servicios;
    }
```

As you can see, the function just returns an array filled up with as many objects as rows there is in the table. The PHP page would call this method, and then print the table with the selected data inside (there is no problem with this).

The thing is how can I print it in the specific section (div with id='datos') previously mentioned, which simply is:

```
<section class="principal">

    <div id="datos">

    </div>

</section>
```

I kinda of have an idea but I really don't know to implement it. Maybe using a document.ready function in jQuery calling the PHP code? I would really like to use this language even if it is a very tiny function in order to learn.

Comment: "_I would really like to use this language_" Do you mean jQuery? If so, you need to look into Ajax. If not, the easiest and most proper way would be to change your `.html` file into a `.php` file and call it directly.

Comment: I've done something with jQuery in another page, so I would like to mantain the flow and learn aswell. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery's load function to load content via a remote file into the div. But you will need to update your `listaServicios` to return html instead of the array.

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#datos').load('phpfile.php');
});
```

**phpfile.php**

```
<?php
   $serv = new Servicio();
   echo $serv->listaServicios();
?>
```

Comment: I've thought in somethink like, in the .php file:

<?php
    include_once "clases/servicio.php";

    $tabla; //table
    $servicios = Servicio::listaServicios();

   //Fill data
    
    echo $tabla;
?>
Do you think it's fine?

Comment: @DannAsekas, yes however you need to implement the PHP. My PHP was more of an example to show you to use a separate php file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to your question depends on the interface of your future application you want to reach.
If you want some kind of [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), then you should make AJAX-requests using JavaScript (jQuery or something else) and create a separate controller to response with data.

But I think in your particular case you can do everything on server side.
First of all you should add new method to your class, name f.e. *render*:

```
public static function render(){
    $services = static::listaServicios();
    include 'path/to/your/template.php';
}
```

Then inside your *template.php* write next:

```
<section class="principal">

    <div id="datos">
        <?php 
             foreach($services as $service) {
                  // echo your $service here as you wish
             }
        ?>
    </div>

</section>
```

So after calling `render()` PHP will render that part of template.

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties of `Servicio` is better you construct your table in php:

```
<?php $servicios = Servicio::listaServicios(); ?>
<section class="principal">
  <div id="datos">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach ($servicios as $servicio): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= $servicio->getDescripcion() ?></td>
          <td><?= $servicio->getPrecio() ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```